# Frame accurate Video in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

I am working in a project where I have to move my video player frame by frame,our flex guys have developed a player for playing videos where they are playing the video object by using NetStream.resume() method.Now I have to get all the frames in the video so that when user does next or previous I can move to the particular frame. For that I planned to get the whole NetStream into a byte array and populate each frame, where my each frame is a byte array, and I can play each frame by frame, But Not able to get the bytes in NetStream object, Could any one suggest how to get that?

Thanks
Sougata

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about getting NetStream data into a byteArray.
But the easiest to move to a particular frame would be NetStream.seek() method.
This method seeks the keyframe closest to the specified location, so you can always seek next or previous.

- Note: This method seeks in seconds.
- You can read more at [Controlling video playback](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d4d.html)

Comment: That sound okay, but is there any other way I can read the whole byte stream,So that I can calculate the frames, and allow user to edit on frame level?

Comment: IMHO, it would be a lot of work on the client unless truly required.  I would rather suggest using a tool like FFMPEG on server side to get all the required metadata for the video. There after you can receive all this data in the onMetaData event of the NetStream Object.

Comment: My requirement would be like getting hold of each and every images, say I have a video of 1 sec with 30fps, so I will have 30 images, I want to move between 30 images(frames), so that I can edit/delete/replace each and every frames, Not sure how to get that thing done in flex, form the server side we can process with some api and return him flex the frames, and ask flex to render image array. But this would be need lot of time. Cos the videos we are reading from a URL and we have to transcode the video in server side and the return to flex and flex has to process that.

Comment: Apparently, NetStream is a video file in binary data format passed by channeling through a NetConnection object. Hence getting each frame out of it is not possible and neither does Flex provide any api for it. In this scenario, some pre-processing on the server using a proxy etc seems like the best possible solution. Hope you find a better and more suitable solution for your requirement. All the best :)